# DRF Serializer Relations / JSON API Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

*Update 1: Attempts with corresponding errors now shown in serializer code

*Update 2: I've narrowed the issue to a conflict with the [JSON Api framework](http://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html) I'm using

I'm fairly new to Python and Django and I'm struggling quite a bit with relations. I'm able to create the relations in the database however I've been unable to serialize the models together for a response object, despite trying every method in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) which seems very straightforward. My goal is to return both models from an APIView on login and if this code doesn't error I get a response with just the user model. The errors vary based on the different techniques and are similar to what other users get when having trouble with relations, however their fixes haven't solved my problem.

I'm wondering if there's something obvious I'm not doing right. I'm happy to share more code but I'm really at a loss as to how to proceed.

Fyi: My models are in different apps which is why the fk reference is users.User

Models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_business = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User',
        related_name='business',
        unique=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    has_driver = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    token = srs.SerializerMethodField()

biz = BusinessSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, 
source='business.id')
error: just returns user model

biz = BusinessSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, source='business')
error: ForeignKey&#39; object has no attribute

biz = serializers.RelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
error: 'User' object has no attribute 'biz'

biz = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='businesses.id')
error: RelatedManager object at 0x7fed496fe208&gt; is not JSON 
serializable

biz = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
error:'User' object has no attribute 'biz'

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'token', 'has_business', 'biz')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):

        user = models.User(
                email = validated_data['email'],
                name = validated_data['name'],
                phone = validated_data['phone'],
                location = validated_data['location'],
            )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

View:

```
class LoginUser(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    resource_name = 'users'

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.POST.get('email', False)
        password = request.POST.get('password', False)

        if(email and password):

            lu = UserAuth()
            authenticated_user = lu.auth(email=email, password=password) 

            if authenticated_user is not None:
                if authenticated_user.is_active:

                    serializer = serializers.UserSerializer(authenticated_user, context={'request': request})
                    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Well you haven't got any serializer code here relating those two models. You should show what you tried and the errors you got.

Comment: Your `UserSerializer` do not contains any relations... You got a `biz` field not related to any of the fields of your `User` model.

Comment: Thanks guys. I added the attempts with errors to the serializer code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the related_name in your serializer.

You can take a look [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

In this example you can see that the Track Model (analog to your Business Model) has the field called `album` with related_name='tracks'

Then in the AlbumSerializer (the analog to your User Model):

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

So, in summary you have to use your related_name `business`

This is the example with a StringRelatedField, but you can of course return the complete object using [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: Getting the "ForeignKey object has no attribute" error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using a beta version (pip install djangorestframework-jsonapi==2.0.0-beta.1) of the [JSON API Framework](http://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html) and it wasn't handling relations very well. I picked the beta because it was the one the documentation lists which is kind of odd. You have to dig a bit for the more stable versions. I'm embarrassed to say how long that took me to figure out.

Here's the stable version as of this day: pip install djangorestframework-jsonapi==2.2.0